# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading the text file using the following code.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\"\|\"', keep_default_na=False, quotechar="~", engine='python', encoding='ISO-8859-1').applymap(str).applymap(lambda x: x.strip("\""))
```

Now I need to write into another text file changing the separator. So I am using the below code to write to text file.

```
df.to_csv(file_path, sep=',', header=None, index=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

While writing to file I am getting the below error. I tried changing to different encoding. Nothing worked. can someone help me.

```
File "C:\Users\ss\PycharmProjects\RepoGeneration\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1524, in to_csv
formatter.save()
File "C:\Users\ss\PycharmProjects\RepoGeneration\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1652, in save
self._save()
File "C:\Users\ss\PycharmProjects\RepoGeneration\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1754, in _save
self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
File "C:\Users\ss\PycharmProjects\RepoGeneration\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py", line 1780, in _save_chunk
lib.write_csv_rows(self.data, ix, self.nlevels, self.cols, self.writer)
File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 1052, in pandas._libs.lib.write_csv_rows
File "C:\Users\ss\PycharmProjects\RepoGeneration\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 555, in writerows
data = data.decode("utf-8")
File "C:\Users\ss\PycharmProjects\RepoGeneration\venv\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3304: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Python2 or python3?

Comment: I am using Python version 2.7.14

Comment: `0xe9` is unicode or ISO-8859-1 code for *LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE*: `é`. This is an unicode *decode* error while trying to *write* into a csv file. That means that pandas tries to interpret a byte string as an UTF8 encode one, while it is not. It is weird if the data has been unchanged since it was read without error as UTF8...